# C: invalid operands to binary expressions (не пойму, как делить, если нельзя делить указатель)

Tags: c, cs50

Не могу понять, как мне совершить деление. Выдает **invalid operands to binary expressions**. Проблема в строке 25, *tax = tax_percent / 100 * bill_amount* (и похоже, такая же ошибка тогда вылезет в *tip = tip_percent / 100 * tax_bill*). Порывшись в интернете, поняла только, что причина в том, что *tax _percent* это указатель. При попытке поставить *(float)tax_percent* выдает ошибку **pointer cannot be cast  to type float**. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне тогда разделить?

```
// Data types, operations, type casting, return value

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float half(float bill, float tax, int tip);

int main(void)
{
    float bill_amount = get_float("Bill before tax and tip: ");
    float tax_percent = get_float("Sale Tax Percent: ");
    int tip_percent = get_int("Tip percent: ");

    printf("You will owe $%.2f each!\n", half(bill_amount, tax_percent, tip_percent));
}

// TODO: Complete the function
float half(float bill, float tax, int tip)
{
    float tax_percent();
    float bill_amount();
    float tip_percent();
    //Convert tax percent into float. Bill times tax.
    tax = tax_percent / 100 * bill_amount;


    //Add tax to the bill
    float tax_bill = tax + bill_amount;

    //Convert tip percent into float. Bill times tip.
    tip = tip_percent / 100 * tax_bill;

    //Add tip to the bill and the tax
    bill = tax_bill + tip;

    //Divide it in two
    return bill / 2;
}'''
```

Comment: `float tax_percent();` - это объявление функции, а не локальной переменной, значения по идее передаются из `main`.

Comment: Может быть, не надо было это писать… но без этого с тем же *tax_percent* была ошибка **undeclared identifier**… Попыталась самостоятельно разобраться и пришла к выводу, что, может, так эта проблема уберется. Убралась. Теперь окончательно запуталась 

Comment: Наоборот, надо было написать про изначальную проблему, а не про свои попытки их решить. А так это проблема XY.

Comment: Так я была уверена, что ту проблему я решила, раз она не вылезла. А в вашем сообществе, как я поняла, не приветствуется, если сам не пытаешься разобраться, прежде чем спрашивать. Вот я и попыталась разобраться и думала, что часть проблем решена 

Comment: Эээ, нет. Проблема может считаться решенной, только если причина ее появления определена и устранена. А тут скорее имеет место безуспешная попытка сделать так, чтобы компилятор не ругался. Самостоятельно пытаться разобраться обязательно нужно, однако вопрос должен фокусироваться на изначальной проблеме.

Answer (score 0):

Просто уберите скобочки в объявлениях переменных:

```
float tax_percent;
float bill_amount;
float tip_percent;
```

Со скобочками они выглядят как функции, а не переменные, поэтому и возникает ошибка.

Правда, остаётся ещё вопрос с инициализацией этих переменных (им не присвоено никакое значение), но это уже к вам вопрос.

Comment: А как я дам им значение, если у меня программа должна запрашивать их значение? И в зависимости от этого считать… вот это я и не понимаю. Я только из-за ошибки инициализации и добавила эти три строки, думала, надо в этой функции еще раз обозначить, что это float, а получилось, сделала из них функции… 

Comment: Могу я написать, что они равны х, y и z или это не решит ошибку инициализации? Временно нет возможности проверить, но мне кажется, тогда возникнут вопросы, что такое x, y и z…

Answer (score 0):

Ну вы же запросили уже эти значения в функции `main()`. И передали их в функцию `half()`. Вам не нужно заново определять эти переменные.
Просто внутри функции значения этих переменных присвоены переменным, которые вы указали в сигнатуре (описании) функции.

```
float half(float bill, float tax, int tip);

// вызов
printf("You will owe $%.2f each!\n", half(bill_amount, tax_percent, tip_percent));
```

Т.е. значение `bill_amount` присвоено переменной `bill`, `tax_percent` - `tax`, `tip_percent` - `tip`.
После этого есть 3 варианта работы:
1 - самый простой, перепишите сигнатуру функции, чтобы переменные назывались также, как в `main()`

```
// сигнатура функции с другими именами параметров
float half(float bill_amount, float tax_percent, int tip_percent)
{
//    float tax_percent();  // удалить
//    float bill_amount();  // удалить
//    float tip_percent();  // удалить
    //Convert tax percent into float. Bill times tax.
    tax_percent = tax_percent / 100 * bill_amount;
....
```

2 - переписать весь код внутри `half()` с использованием новых переменных

```
float half(float bill, float tax, int tip)
{
    //Convert tax percent into float. Bill times tax.
// вместо
//    tax = tax_percent / 100 * bill_amount;

// переписываете все операции с новыми именами из параметров функции
    float tip_percent = tip;  // нужно для использования типа float вместо int
    tax = tax / 100.0 * bill;
    bill += tax; //Add tax to the bill
    tip_percent = tip_percent / 100.0 * tax; //Convert tip percent into float. Bill times tip.
    bill += tip_percent; //Add tip to the bill and the tax

    return bill / 2;  //Divide it in two
}
```

3 - костыль, вместо него лучше использовать 1 вариант. Потому что так получается дублирование значений в 2 переменных и можете сами запутаться, когда какое использовать.

```
float half(float bill, float tax, int tip)
{
    float tax_percent = tax;
    float bill_amount = bill;
    float tip_percent = tip;
 
   //Convert tax percent into float. Bill times tax.
    tax_percent = tax_percent / 100 * bill_amount;
....
```

---

UPD
Собственно всё работает и без изменения объявления функции и без введения кучи дополнительных переменных.

```
float half(float bill, float tax, int tip)
{
    float tip_percent = tip;  // нужно для использования типа float вместо int
    tax = bill * tax / 100.0;
    bill = bill + tax;
    tip_percent = bill * tip_percent / 100.0;
    bill += tip_percent;
    return bill / 2.0;
}
```

И в принципе можно ещё укоротить

```
float half(float bill, float tax, int tip)
{
    float tip_percent = tip;  // нужно для использования типа float вместо int
    bill += bill * tax / 100.0;
    bill += bill * tip_percent / 100.0;
    return bill / 2.0;
}
```

И поскольку переменной `tip` больше не присваиваются значения, то можно прямо её использовать в расчетах - она автоматически приведется к типу `float`(т.к. при умножении `float` на `int` результат операции будет иметь тип `float`)

```
float half(float bill, float tax, int tip)
{
    bill += bill * tax / 100.0;
    bill += bill * tip / 100.0;
    return bill / 2.0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, что нашли время на такое подробное разъяснение!  Дело в том, что это доп.задание из CS50, и строка *float half (float bill, float tax, float tip)* была задана, и я не уверена, что ее можно менять. Но я попробую несколько разных вариантов, посмотрю, что примут. Еще раз спасибо, очень помогли ☺️

Comment: Если нельзя менять - тогда ваши варианты №2 (лучше) и №3 (хуже).

Comment: И у вас в комментарии `half( ,  , float tip)`, а в задании `half( ,  , int tip)` - разный тип данных у параметра `tip`. Я думаю что правильней всё-таки `float`. И спасибо здесь - принятый ответ.

Comment: Да, это int было изначально, в комментарии по заданию сказано привести tip_percent к типу float. Я в комментарии опечаталась, а правку уже не внести

Comment: Ну вот во 2 примере я дополнил - приведение типа от `int` к `float`.

Comment: Cейчас вставила Ваш код от и до, со всеми переменными, с ним проблема запуска программы решилась, но данные она выдает не те, которые дали для проверки правильности работы, если не менять аргумент в строке функции c int tip на float tip. Выдает 53.69 вместо 62.69. Если поменять тип аргумента в строке функции (я была уверена, что этого делать нельзя), получается все верно. Поэтому и был задан новый вопрос. Проблема другая возникла.

Comment: А какие исходные данные? Это нужно указывать в вопросе. А написанный вами код в таком виде, даже с заменой типа переменной `tip`, будет работать неправильно.

Comment: Ну я же изначально не подозревала, что будет неправильно работать... Вопрос на тот момент был не  в том, почему работает неправильно, а почему не работает вообще никак, выдавая указанную в заголовке ошибку... Поэтому переменные никакие не давала. Для проверки даны три набора переменных bill, tax и tip соответственно: 100, 6.25 и 18; 12.50, 8.875 и 20; и 23.50, 7 и 15.

Comment: Отправила без ответов... Для проверки даны три набора переменных bill, tax и tip соответственно: 100, 6.25 и 18 с результатом 62.69; 12.50, 8.875 и 20 с результатом 8.17; и 23.50, 7 и 15 с результатом 14.46.

Comment: Нормально работает код и без изменения сигнатуры функции - добавил в ответ.