# Из-за чего float округляет до целых? Ответ типа 19.00, когда должен быть 19.13

Tags: c, cs50

Доп.задача из первой недели CS50: вычислить, сколько каждый будет должен в ресторане с учетом налога и чаевых. Опытным путем было обнаружено, что проблема именно с переменной *tip*. Заключается она в том, что программа видит ее как *float* (если запрашиваю *return tip*, выдает не 19, а именно 19.00), но округляет до целых, хоть кол на голове теши. Что может быть не так? Код прикладываю с *return bill_sum / 2*, как и требуется в задаче.

**UPD** Видимо, stackoverflow не для тупых, если я, пытаясь разобраться, сижу до глубокой ночи, вставая по утрам в 6, просто потому что мне интересно и ХОЧЕТСЯ разобраться, и при этом за второй мой вопрос из трех голосуют -1, будто разобраться я не пыталась...

```
// Data types, operations, type casting, return value

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float half(float bill, float tax, int tip);

int main(void)
{
    float bill_amount = get_float("Bill before tax and tip: ");
    float tax_percent = get_float("Sale Tax Percent: ");
    int tip_percent = get_int("Tip percent: ");

    printf("You will owe $%.2f each!\n", half(bill_amount, tax_percent, tip_percent));
}

// TODO: Complete the function
float half(float bill, float tax, int tip)
{
    float tax_percent = tax;
    float bill_amount = bill;
    int tip_percent = tip;
    //Convert tax percent into float. Bill times tax.
    tax = bill * tax / 100;

    //Add tax to the bill
    float bill_tax = bill + tax;

    //Convert tip percent into float. Bill times tip.
    tip = (float)tip;
    tip = bill_tax * tip / 100;

    //Add tip to the bill and the tax
    float bill_sum = tip + bill_tax;

    //Divide it in two
    return bill_sum / 2;
}
```

Comment: return bill_sum / 2.0;  И все 100 заменить на 100.0

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Интересно как!

> Опытным путем было обнаружено, что проблема именно с переменной tip. Заключается она в том, что программа видит ее как float (если запрашиваю return tip, выдает не 19, а именно 19.00), но округляет до целых, хоть кол на голове теши.

Каким же образом программа видит переменную `tip` как `float`, если она явно объявлена как `int`?

```
float half(float bill, float tax, int tip)
```

> Из-за чего float округляет до целых?

Ничего никто не округляет, просто вы в расчетах используете переменную типа `int`, и при присвоении дробного значения переменной целого типа дробная часть числа отбрасывается.
C++ - язык со статической типизацией - если объявили переменную, то тип у неё уже не изменить. Вот эта ваша запись абсолютно бессмысленна - нельзя сконвертировать переменную.  Можно сконвертировать значение переменной, присвоив его другой переменной типа `float`.

```
// вот это - бессмысленно tip по-прежнему остается int
    tip = (float)tip; //Convert tip percent into float. Bill times tip.

// должно быть как-то так
float tip_percent = tip;
```

И если вы пытаетесь вернуть `tip`, как раз и происходит приведение типа из `int` во `float`, т.к. ваша функция возвращает `float`.

```
float half(float bill, float tax, int tip)
{
    ....
    return tip;
}
```

Вам в самом начале функции необходимо завести переменную типа `float` и далее в расчетах использовать её везде, вместо `tip`.

```
float half(float bill, float tax, int tip)
{
    float tip_percent = tip;
    // далее везде использовать tip_percent вместо tip
    ....
}
```

Вы уже задавали вопрос с этим кодом и я уже писал там рабочий код. Почему опять он возник?
[ранее заданный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1498447/c-invalid-operands-to-binary-expressions-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB/)

Comment: Полагаю, вы имели ввиду статическую типизацию. У с++ нестрогая типизация.

Comment: @needKVAS да. Но объяснить девушке ещё термин статическая - уже выше моих сил. Здесь я имел ввиду общечеловеческое "строгая" :) Но на всякий случай поменяю, спасибо!

Comment: @DmitryK Про то, что _float half(float bill, float tax, int tip)_ было задано CS50, я писала в предыдущем вопросе. Я была уверена, что этот заданный аргумент нельзя менять и нужно прописать код так, чтобы получалась замена _int_ на _float_. Я прошу прощения, что вставила сюда вариант кода с int, просто даже подставив Ваш код, Дмитрий, у меня не получалось нужное значение. _bill_sum / 2_ выходило 62.62 вместо 62.69. И я до полвторого ночи пыталась разобраться, поэтому, наверно, перепробовав все возможные варианты, забыла исправить _int_ обратно на _float_.

Comment: @DmitryK Переменные в коде я оставила свои, чтобы не запутаться. Сейчас поменяла в аргументах функции _int tip_ на _float tip_, только так считает всё верно… Хотя мне казалось, что данные задачи менять нельзя, но, по-моему, я и это пробовала вчера. Наверно, в коде функции что-то не так на тот момент было. Сейчас пазл сложился.